# Using PHP and JS to display images in div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

#### Disclaimer: this is for an assignment. I am not asking for explicit code. I only want enough information so that I may understand the task at hand and learn the associative parts.

I'm working on an assignment that requires me to accept a name and a picture through a form, put both into a database, then display all the names in the database below the form. The names are supposed to be clickable, and on click, display their respective picture in a div below the names.

I have gotten far enough to store the names and images in the database (I know, storing images in a database is bad, but it's part of the assignment.) The last part I have to finish is the linking and image display.

I have decided to give each name its own div, in a fairly reckless fashion:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $nrows; $i++) {
    $name = htmlspecialchars(mysql_result($results, $i, "first_name")). " " .htmlspecialchars(mysql_result($results, $i, "last_name"));
    echo "<div id='".$name."'>";
    echo $name;
    echo "</div>";
}
```

So this works like a table, except each div has a unique ID (the name of the person, though I could change this to a numeric ID.) I figure it's fairly elementary to give an on-click function to each div, based on its unique id, but I'm not certain if I should do that within the bounds of the loop or outside...

Furthermore, I'm not exactly sure how to set up that on-click function to select the image of the specific name. Each image is stored as a LONGBLOB and as such needs to be encoded into an image form before being displayed. I know that base64_encode should work for this, but I can't seem to put it together in my head.

Please let me know if you need more of my code - I'll be happy to supply it. Otherwise, thank you for your time and your assistance.

#### Edit #1 (11:44am, 2/18/13):

```
$('#$name').click(function() {
    $("#image-div").html("<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode(mysql_result($results, $i, 'photo')).'>");
});
```

Comment: @roXon I left out the attempts at implementing an image display. I'll add what I've been working on.

Comment: in your edit, are you sure you're not mixing JS with PHP syntax?

Comment: Is it because you're ending the src='' attribute too early? Shouldn't the closing single quote of src='' come after the base64_encode? And also...think twice about encode vs. decode. If its stored encoded...you would want to decode it.

Comment: @mimber It's stored as binary data in the database, or at least I believe it is. I'm not sure about the quotes - these multiple quotes always confuse the hell out of me :/

Comment: @howderek I'm asking if anyone can explain the concepts of this implementation to me, as I'm not finding what I need elsewhere.

Comment: @idigyourpast ok i gotcha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Give the divs a class then you can use `jQuery.on` to assign your click handler via a class selector
2. To retrive your images you need to create a *controller* to push the image down to the client with the proper content-type header; this makes your image tags look somehting like: `<img src="image.php?name=theimagename" />`

**UPDATE**:

you dont want to put the id directly in the js... you want to use some sort of attribute you can get at from the handler. For example:

```
<div id="theimagename" data-image-id="1">
</div>
```

Then from within the handler you can get the value of `data-image-id` and send it along to php.

Comment: So since the image name is determined dynamically, how do I pass that into the image.php file? Or, do I use the variable name at the end of your string, so something like "image.php?name=$image"?

Comment: You can use the variable, however keep in mind you have to query on the value with mysql so i would recommend using the primary key that is unique as opposed to a field that might have multiple query results.

Comment: Okay, I think I have a valid controller, but the click handler is something I'm still unfamiliar with. As best as I can tell, this should work:   $('#$id').click(function() {
    $("#image-div").html("<img src='get.php?id=$id'>");
  });
But it causes my page to throw a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

For each of the `<div id="name">`, also add `onclick` handler like this:

`<div onclick="getImage(this.id)" id="name">`

Then the `getImage()` function can have the following:

```
function getImage(name){
  console.log(id)
  //Now you have the name of the image you need
}
```